# Is there a way to push code to Github and Dropbox at the same time without having to push twice to each location?

Tags: git, sync, dropbox

I use Dropbox for Class Assignments and Github for publicly showcasing all my work.

I want to push a Dropbox repository to Github, but currently I do that by using the [`git-remote-dropbox`](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox) tool to push a local repo to both Dropbox **and** Github, which is time-consuming.

However, Dropbox seems to have a separate version control system compared to Git, so I'm not sure if saving the original repo on Dropbox and pushing that to Github is a good idea either.

I want to push once from Dropbox to Github instead of twice to both from a local repo.

Comment: Very confused. It seems like [`git-remote-dropbox`](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox) does exactly what you state you want to do. When you say “time consuming” what do you mean? It seems like you just need to use `git-remote-dropbox`, issue one command maybe wait slightly longer than normally if it were just a `git push`? What exactly is your concern or issue?

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that I can push a Dropbox repo straight from Dropbox to Github with the remote?

Comment: I’m not saying anything, but what I am saying your question is unclear. It seems like  [`git-remote-dropbox`](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox) does what you want to do; sends items to Github as well as Dropbox. So what is the real question here. What exactly do you think is “time consuming?”

Comment: Oh well I wanted to push once from Dropbox to Github instead of twice to both from a local repo.